# ¿Cuál es la función final de este archivo?

Tags: c++, visual-studio

En la clase de programación estamos aprendiendo a hacer programas de c++ en visual studio 2012 y me fije que adentro de la carpeta de mi proyecto estaban unos archivos de los cuales el que mas me llamo la atención fue este. Alguien me podría decir para que es este archivo y si hay una manera de eliminarlo ya que veo que usa mas espacio que la misma aplicación?
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1):

Sin ver la extensión ni la descripción completa del Tipo, haré mi apuesta.

#### IntelliSense.

Se trata del archivo `*.sdf` del Tipo "*SQL Server Compact Edition Database File*"; este formato de archivo substituye al archivo `*.ncb` de versiones anteriores de Visual Studio.

Tanto los archivos `*.sdf` como los `*.ncb` almacenan información de [IntelliSense](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/IntelliSense) para dar soporte a las utilidades de auto-completar.

#### Puedes borrarlo.

Dado que el archivo sólo contiene información para la ayuda y soporte al desarrollo, no va a parar a tu ejecutable compilado, puedes borrarlo (siempre y cuando tengas cerrado Visual Studio) sin efecto alguno, pero la próxima vez que abras el proyecto Visual Studio lo volverá a generar (pudiendo notar una ralentización del IDE). Por este motivo, te aconsejo ponerlo en tu lista de extensiones ignoradas si tienes tu proyecto bajo algún tipo de software de control de versiones.

#### Puedes desactivarlo.

También es posible desactivar IntelliSense, esto reducirá el tamaño del archivo `*.sdf` o `*.ncb` (o evitará su creación) pero a la vez no dispondrás de las opciones de auto-completado.

Para [desactivar esta opción](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hcw1s69b.aspx) dirigete a **Herramientas -> Opciones -> Editor de Texto** y desactiva las opciones de "*Información de Parámetros*" y "*Mostrar miembros automáticamente*".

Tienes más información sobre el control de IntelliSense en [este artículo](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2010/03/09/intellisensebrowsing-options-in-vc-2010/) (en inglés) del equipo de desarrollo de Visual Studio.

Comment: Lo desactive 
Pero hice eso antes de empezar a ingresar elementos en mi formulario.
Cuando lo hice no me dejo arrastrar elementos al formulario